# What's purpose of "arm64/kernel/asm-offsets.c"?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kvm, arm64

I am trying to look into what is defined in "arch/arm64/kernel/asm-offsets.c".

But don't understand the purpose of this file, what it actually contains?

For example:

```
DEFINE(KVM_TIMER_CNTVOFF,     offsetof(struct kvm, arch.timer.cntvoff));
```

What it meant by above definition, is arch.timer.cntvoff mapped to actually mapped actuall CNTVOFF_EL2 register?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This file contains definitions that are needed for the modules written in assembler, for example in case of `KVM_TIMER_CNTVOFF` it generates a symbol with the same name which contains the offset of `arch.timer.cntvoff` field from the beginning of the `kvm` struct (using `offsetof` macro: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/include/linux/kernel.h#L15).

So, if you have this, you can use these symbols to access the structure fields in the asm like here: http://tomoyo.osdn.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/arch/arm/kvm/interrupts_head.S#L555

```
555         ldr     r4, [vcpu, #VCPU_KVM]
556         ldr     r2, [r4, #KVM_TIMER_ENABLED]
557         cmp     r2, #0
558         beq     1f
559 
560         ldr     r2, [r4, #KVM_TIMER_CNTVOFF]
561         ldr     r3, [r4, #(KVM_TIMER_CNTVOFF + 4)]
562         mcrr    p15, 4, rr_lo_hi(r2, r3), c14   @ CNTVOFF
563
```

So, in r4, you have the address of `struct kvm` instance and with

```
ldr     r2, [r4, #KVM_TIMER_CNTVOFF]
```

you're accessing the field `KVM_TIMER_CNTVOFF`.

Comment: Thanks @Nemanja for your answer and sorry could not appreciate it earlier.One more thing I would like, if I have to defined NEW variable(same like KVM_TIMER_CNTVOFF) and later on reference it in ASM block?

Comment: You're welcome. If I understand what you're asking: so, if you want to add new field to struct and to access it from asm, you should add the new `DEFINE` into `asm-offsets.c`. I'm not sure from top of my head, but then there should be something in build which would generate `.s` file with symbols from this file which you would use for asm step.

Comment: Ok, I understand it that I need to add new DEFINE into asm-offsets.c but how  #define KVM_TIMER_CNTVOFF 1000, would I define this number 1000 for new variable ? Also is it possible to define a variable(Not a structure member) that can be referenced in ASM block?

Comment: (Note it's not `#define` but `DEFINE`). No, you can utilize this only for the offsets not for the variables. For accessing variables I assume `IMPORT` and `=globvar` should do the trick. See http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0040d/Cihcciij.html

Comment: Ok fine, I see your point here but isn't it here http://tomoyo.osdn.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/arch/arm/kvm/interrupts_head.S#L564 , we are taking the reference of =VCPU_TIMER_CNTV_CVAL ?

Comment: It's still working with the offset. So, you store the offset of the field in r4 (`ldr r4, =VCPU_TIMER_CNTV_CVAL`), and you add it with the beginning of the structure and store the result in r5 (`add r5, vcpu, r4`) and then you have the address of that field in r5. Then, we store r2, r3 double word to that field with `strd r2, r3, [r5]` if this makes sense?

Comment: (note that my arm is a little bit rusty, so I might be wrong, but I think this is correct)